# Blade not supporting nested yields

Tags: php, laravel-5.1, laravel-blade

I have a sample view:

File: hello.blade.php

```
//includes the basic html enclosed tags
<p>Hello world<p>
@yield('content')
```

File: tester.blade.php

```
@extends('hello')
@section('content')
  <p>this is a test<p>
  @yield('contents') 
@endsection
```

File: content.blade.php

```
@extends('tester.blade.php')
@section('contents')
  <p>any code will do<p>
@endsection
```

now my problem is whenever it only renders

```
Hello world
this is a test
```

is there any workaround this? or blade engine does not support nested yields? anyhelp will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

I have not tested but you could try change `content.blade.php` to

```
@extends('tester')
```

and make sure you use

```
return view('content');
```

However `@include` inside `@section` works. or using `@parent` in `content.blade.php`

```
@extends('tester')
@section('content')
   @parent 
   <p>any code will do</p>
@endsection
```

`@parent` will cause Blade to append parent view content with current view rather than overwrite whole section.

Comment: Thanks, corrected the extends but unfortunately I forgot to return the child view, and thats what's causing the non rendering of the page

Answer (score 0):

I've tested it but doesn't do what we expect.

But there is one solution that I still use when I'm facing to such situation. I use `@parent` blade directive like this

File: hello.blade.php

```
{{-- includes the basic html enclosed tags --}}
<p>Hello world<p>
@yield('content')
```

File: tester.blade.php

```
@extends('hello')
@section('content')
  <p>this is a test<p>
  @yield('contents') 
@endsection
```

File: content.blade.php

```
@extends('tester.blade.php')
@section('contents')
  @parent
  <p>any code will do<p>
@endsection
```